# At what point should carrots be thrown away?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, carrots

We tend to buy a big bag of carrots from the supermarket (mainly because it's cheaper than a small bag), but usually these are starting to go soft halfway through the week.  My current rule of thumb is that I'll cook them until they are so soft that I just can't peel them, and won't eat them raw after they have started to go soft.

Given that this is entirely based on my guesswork, can anyone tell me at what point they are *actually* inedible?

Comment: I cannot answer the at which point are they inedible, but [this link](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15517/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-carrots?rq=1) addresses the storage question.

Comment: how cold is your refrigerator?

Comment: Related Q: How to properly store carrots http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/15517/6808

Comment: I edited out the second part of your question because it's a duplicate of the link I posted above. This way, answers here can focus on your main question - how to tell if carrots have become inedible.

Comment: If you can tie a knot in them, it's probably time to toss them. :^D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your carrots are going soft after just a few days, you're not storing them properly. Mine keep for weeks and weeks. I leave them in the plastic bag, and keep that in one of the vegetable drawers in my fridge. How are you storing yours?

A rubbery soft carrot isn't bad for you, it just isn't very pleasant. A slimy carrot is bad for you, don't eat it.

Comment: And you can typically resuscitate softening carrots by wrapping them in damp paper towels and allowing them to rehydrate.

Comment: I'd like to add that when you store them in the plastic-bag in the fridge, make sure you do NOT have water collecting at the bottom of the bag. I usually put a paper-towel in what ends up being the bottom, because sometimes (not always.. depends a lot on the weather naturally!) I end up having some condensed water in the plastic-packaging.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, carrots last for a really long time in the fridge. I usually toss them out when they get that white, dry coating on them. In addition, there should be a 'best buy' date on the bag; use this as a general guideline, but most of the time, they are good past then.

Fresh, whole carrots should last about 4-5 weeks in the fridge. Baby carrots last for about 3-4 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

If they bend they are not fresh and may lack a bit of vitamins but will not hurt you, be sure to boil them if they are older then 2 weeks from buy time, mine last about 4 weeks in the fridge, but after about 7 to 10 days they will get softer, they will get a white chalky looking coating after about 3 weeks but if smell funny or slimey do not eat.

Answer (score 0):

If they are just going soft and not slimy then it is time to make cream of carrot soup. In fact it is a good idea to make a pot of soup at the end of every week to use up veggies that ore not so fresh any more AND make a list of things to restock!