# Ways to Store Carrots for more days

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, food-preservation, refrigerator, carrots

I recently brought a whole 2KG bag of carrots. They seemed fine the day I brought, but eventually, the skin of the carrot evolved to a black layer. However, when I peeled them off, the carrot looks perfectly fine. Is it good to continue using these carrots ? Are there any precautions that I have to take to store them ?

Please find the reference images.

[image: Bag of carrots]

This is how most of the carrots now look :
[image: Spoiled carrots]

After peeling the carrots that are black :
[image: After peeling]

Comment: What do you mean by "eventually"? How long did it take for the carrots to develop the black skin? Did you store them in the refrigerator?

Comment: Ya, I kept them in the refrigerator as soon as I bought them. It took 2 days to develop that black coat on carrot skin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to store carrots?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15517/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-carrots)

Comment: 2 days is nothing for carrots, they should stay good much longer than that. It doesn't sound like you did anything wrong, you were sold bad carrots.

Comment: I can regularly get 4-6 weeks out of carrots.  In a worst case scenario, they'll start to put out little hair-like roots as a sign of age.  2 days is likely a sign that something was wrong well before you brought them home.  (if it's not, then it's a sign that something is horribly, horribly wrong in your fridge)

Answer (score 10):

I have worked in the CPG industry for almost 30 years. A few years back I had the privilege of representing one of the largest produce brands in the US. I learned quite a bit about produce storage and what speeds up the deterioration rate.

One thing I noticed in your picture is that there appeared to be moisture (condensation) inside of the bag of carrots. It is certainly okay to leave them in the bag they were purchased in, but you want to be absolutely sure that there is no moisture in the bag. Moisture can be a real devil when it comes to mold and mildew or other fungus.

Another very important thing that affects the length of time produce will remain good is air circulation. You have to have really good air circulation around produce. Bagged salads, slaws, etc. will go bad quicker (even if they are unopened) if they are stored so that they don't have proper air circulation around them. In the case of the carrots, I would recommend opening one end of the bag so that they can get air.

Overall, I would rceommend that produce be stored in the produce crisper in your refrigerator. Crispers are designed to maintain an appropriate temperature and level of humidity that will help produce stay fresh longer.

If your refrigerator does not have a crisper, I would get a plastic rectangular container and place it on the bottom shelf of your refrigerator to use as a make shift crisper. If possible, cut one inch holes generously in the lid to allow for air flow. If you don't have a way to do this, leave the lid off.

Regarding using the carrots, I would be reluctant without knowing with certainty what the black is and probably would not use them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just bought the wrong carrots. Carrots can keep for ages if they are mostly left in their natural state. But the cheap carrots in large German supermarkets tend to be quite processed before being sold. The ends are cut off, and the dirt is removed by some process (I don't know if it's chemical, physical, or both) which destroys their outer skin. This makes them as perishable as any other peeled fruit or vegetable, so just 1-2 days in the fridge. The condensation in the bag makes it even worse.

If you buy carrot bundles from the market, with a little bit of leaves on them and still a bit of dirt, they will keep. The whole leaves look better, but will dessicate them quicker! Or you can buy the whole leaves kind and keep it in wet sand.

Comment: Wet sand? In a big container in the fridge? Does that work for other root veggies too?

Comment: I don't know about a big container in the fridge, we did that in the root cellar when I lived with my parents. The carrots kept throughout the winter. We never kept other root veggies this way - I assume that the tougher skin of potatoes etc. makes them easier to keep without water and sand.

Comment: I guess more suitable for root crops you have grown, or are sure are in a more natural state .. [the way my grandpas did it](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=666) ... (both of them!)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with mold is that it's there even when you can't see it. So it's acceptable to cut off a moldy part of a hard shelled fruit or vegetable but not so for bread or other porous items. Carrots are pretty inexpensive so I recommend throwing them away. Especially if you're planning on eating them raw, as in salad. In the future, keep carrots in a well ventilated chilled environment, or peel the whole lot and keep submerged in cold water, in a refrigerator.

Answer (score 0):

- Store them in refrigerator in a plastic box complety filled with water (more than a week completely fresh)
- Store them in refrigerator in a plastic box each layer separeted by the next one with kitchen paper to prevent moisture (5days nice and perfect without problem)
- Roll each carrot in a slightly umid kitchen paper and put it in a plastic box in refrigerator
- Cellar in a box filled of sand (over the winter), layer by layer covered, recommanded but not tried => they used to do it in the old days so it should work out pretty

=> Best place in refrigerator as low as possible! Dont know if because of humidity, refrigerator design, airflow or temperature.

What i dont know is what is the difference between condensation moisture and moisture that keeps the carrot fresh and prevents that i looses water. To me they should be the same - anybody knows?

I stick to point 2.

Answer (score 0):

When they get the blackening just peel them, dip them in 1 litre chilled  water with a half (or whole) teaspoon of vinegar, then place in a freezer bag (these actually do breethe) in your crisper in the fridge.

Comment: Niel, welcome! Please focus on answering the question ( see [answer]), you will be able to comment on other posts after gaining enough reputation on the site. I recommend you take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about how the site works. If you have questions, we’re here to help!

Answer (score -2):

My gut is telling me not to peel them and stick in the ground, and they will not only last forever, but grow small carrots.

Comment: No, they will not develop small carrots, that’s not how carrots propagate. They would - at best - go to seed, then die. You probably confused carrots any potatoes.

Comment: Upvote, though.. [it's not a bad way of storing carrots](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=666)