# How long will corm vegetables last in a refrigerator and should they be wrapped?

Tags: vegetables, storage-lifetime

How long can corm vegetables - celeriac (celery root), turnips, and swedes (rutabagas) - be kept in a refrigerator? And should they be wrapped? I usually buy them wrapped in sealed plastic. If aiming to store them for as long as possible, should I leave it on, replace it with cloth or greaseproof paper, or perhaps store the vegetables unwrapped?

Comment: As they're root vegetables, I assume your would treat them like carrots : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/15517/67 .  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/46168/67

Comment: They're almost but not quite root vegetables. I find they can easily outlast carrots and parsnips in the fridge.

Comment: You use the term corned. That term has a very specific culinary meaning. It means pickling and the addition of pickling spice. Without the spice it is just pickling. Do you mean pickling by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

how long is long ?

They are fine for couple of weeks if stored in a cool place with good amount of humidity.

"These are dependent on [ideal storage conditions](https://modernfarmer.com/2015/08/how-to-store-root-crops-for-winter/) of 32 to 40 degrees Fahrenheit and 95-percent humidity."

Comment: "*How long is long?*" I have changed "*If aiming to store them for a long time*" to "*If aiming to store them for as long as possible*".